# UI unresponsive until action is complete

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, ftp, winscp

I'm not sure if the Title is a good description of this issue or not. Essentially what I have is a WinForm app that retrieves a list of files from a folder into a ListView, then a button is clicked to upload them via FTP to a remote server.

Functionally speaking, the app works as expected:

1. Open app
2. Review list of files in ListView control
3. Click Upload button
4. Files listed in ListView are uploaded; after each successful upload the ListView is updated to show
   'Success'
5. After all files are uploaded, operation stops.

My issue is, after clicking the upload button the UI is pretty much unresponsive until the operation finishes. The ListView updates as expected as each file is uploaded and even keeps the active row in focus. Here is the for loop that processes the files. A little background - in the code excerpt below, each for...loop processes 2 files - the primary file is the only one that shows in the ListView. The 2nd file in each loop is a trigger file that is sent after its primary is sent, ie: .primary, .trigger. Both files have to send in order to register a success. If a primary file does not have a corresponding trigger file, it won't be available in the ListView for upload.

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in lvSourceFiles.Items)
{
    int rowIndex = item.Index;
    string fileName = item.SubItems[2].Text;

    lvSourceFiles.EnsureVisible(rowIndex);

    transferStatus = "Failed"; // Set this as a default

    // Transfer the source file first
    transferResult = session.PutFiles(readyFile, destFile, false, transferOptions);

    // Throw on any error
    transferResult.Check();

    // If the source file transfer was successful, then transfer the trigger file
    if (transferResult.IsSuccess)
    {
        transferResult = session.PutFiles(triggerFile, destFile, false, transferOptions);
        transferResult.Check();

        if (transferResult.IsSuccess)
        {
            transferStatus = "Success";
        }
    }

    UpdateResultsToListView(lvSourceFiles, rowIndex, fileName, transferStatus);
}
```

Is this a situation where I need to implement some sort of asynchronous functionality, or is there a better way to do this so the UI doesn't freeze during the upload process? Essentially I want to be able to interact with the form while the upload is running, such as having a cancel button to stop the upload. As it stands, I can't do anything with the form until the job completes, or I terminate the app.

Thanks,
James

Comment: my first thoughts to solve this would be a) asynchronous operations or b) a [BackgroundWorker-component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/backgroundworker-component-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) - which was designed exactly for that.

Comment: I had already made an attempt at using the BackgroundWorker component, but being my first attempt, I wasn't really sure how to implement it in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could offload the long-running operation to a `ThreadPool` thread, by using async/await and the handy [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method:

```
transferResult = await Task.Run(() => session.PutFiles(readyFile, destFile, false, transferOptions));
```

...and:

```
transferResult = await Task.Run(() => session.PutFiles(triggerFile, destFile, false, transferOptions));
```

You should also add the [`async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) modifier in the event handler, in order to enable the [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) operator.

**Important:** Avoid doing anything UI related in the offloaded method. If you want to communicate with the UI during the operation, for example for [progress reporting](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/), use the [`Progress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) class.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do lengthy operations on the GUI thread. Do them on a background thread.

The answer by @Theodor correctly shows that you can move the `PutFiles` to the thread pool.

Another option is to move all your upload logic to the thread pool and call back to the main thread using [`Control.Invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke) for GUI updates only.

For a full example, see WinSCP article [Displaying FTP/SFTP transfer progress on WinForms ProgressBar](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_winforms_progressbar).

Pick the option that suits you better. I believe that my approach is easier to grasp for someone unexperienced with thread programming.