# Create a thread and use it to execute functions in the same thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I recently implemented a plugin into my application, there is communication established between my app and the plugin. plugin send something to my app -> my app does some work -> my app informs the plugin that the action is completed.
This is working fine, my issue is the connection to the plugin is created is the UI thread so every time I need to inform the plugin that the action is completed I need to use the UI thread.

what I want is to create a separate thread to create the connection in it and just use it when I need it, executing the completed action in it.

Comment: Thanks, trying it to use task.

Comment: Using async/await and `Task.Run` should solve this problem quite easily. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64003533/ui-unresponsive-until-action-is-complete/64003604#64003604) is an example.